# Partition refinement of a clopen covering in $\Box (\omega+1)^\omega$

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Consider $\omega+1$ with the interval topology, that is $U\subseteq (\omega+1)$ is open if and only if $U\subseteq\omega$ or $(\omega+1)\setminus U$ is finite.

We write $(\omega+1)^\omega$ for the collection of all functions $f:\omega\to(\omega+1)$. Let $\Box (\omega+1)^\omega$ be the set $(\omega+1)^\omega$ endowed with the [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology), where each factor $(\omega+1)$ carries the interval topology.

For each $f\in(\omega+1)^\omega$ we consider the following clopen neighborhood $U_f$ of $f$:

$U_f = \{g\in(\omega+1)^\omega:\forall n\in\omega\big((f(n) < \omega \Rightarrow g(n) = f(n)) \text{ and } (f(n) = \omega \Rightarrow g(n) \in [n,\omega])\big) \}$

Let ${\cal U} = \{U_f: f\in(\omega+1)^\omega\}$. Is there an open covering ${\cal V}$ of $(\omega+1)^\omega$ with the following properties?

- each member of  ${\cal V}$ is contained in some member of ${\cal U}$;
- for $V\neq W \in {\cal V}$ we have $V\cap W = \emptyset$.

**Note:** This is one special case of [this](http://%20mathoverflow.net/q/194281/1946) question, see Joel David Hamkins' comment below.

Comment: See the OP's earlier unanswered related question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/194281/1946.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I am asking now for a very particular case of the question you are referring to. Thanks for linking to that question, I will include it in this post.

Comment: Dominic, although it is a special case, it isn't clear to me that it is any easier than the general case.

Comment: Maybe a special case that is more treatable is if I replace $[n,\omega]$ by $[1,\omega]$ in the definition of $U_f$ (or... if that is trivial, $[2, \omega$]).

Comment: If the answer is affirmative, then the bounded case is certainly easier; but if the answer is negative, then it may be easier to find a counterexample in the general case.

Comment: Can you not just take the $U_f$'s for $f$ such that if $f(n)<\omega$, then $f(n)<n$?

Comment: Eric, my understanding of the question is that we want to find clopen $V_f\subset U_f$ with $f\in V_f$ so that $f\neq g\to V_f\cap V_g=\emptyset$. But I see that the OP did not say this exactly. Dominic, could you clarify?

Comment: Exactly, Joel (and let's not forget $f\in V_f$ for $f\in (\omega+1)^\omega$). I will edit the post accordingly

Comment: Dominic, your edit to the post isn't the same as this! Now Eric's comment seems relevant.

Comment: I see... ! Thanks Eric & Joel! - Can Eric write this as an answer, or is it better to delete the question?

Comment: I think it is fine to keep the question, as long as it is clear what the question is.